# Rails 3.1 Assets Pipeline Precompile Error - couldn't find file 'jquery'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1, sprockets

I'm upgrading a Rails 3.1 app to use the assets pipeline. I have included the 'jquery-rails' gem in my Gemfile and installed by running `bundle install`.

```
Using jquery-rails (1.0.19)
```

My application.js file in app/assets/javascripts directory looks like this:

```
// ...
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery-ui
//= require_tree .
...
```

When I run `bundle exec rake assets:precompile` I get the following error:

```
** Invoke assets:precompile (first_time)
** Execute assets:precompile
/Users/augus164/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/bin/ruby /Users/augus164/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/bin/rake assets:precompile:all RAILS_ENV=production RAILS_GROUPS=assets --trace
** Invoke assets:precompile:all (first_time)
** Execute assets:precompile:all
** Invoke assets:precompile:primary (first_time)
** Invoke assets:environment (first_time)
** Execute assets:environment
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
** Invoke tmp:cache:clear (first_time)
** Execute tmp:cache:clear
** Execute assets:precompile:primary
rake aborted!
couldn't find file 'jquery'
```

It's my understanding that by including jquery-rails gem I don't need to include the jquery library in my javascripts directory, or link to it from the google cdn. Anyone know what I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using rails 3.1 you do not need the gem. It is included by default with rails.

Comment: Right. I guess I should say I un-commented the gem since I wasn't previously using it.